# Length cannot be less than zero

Tags: c#, regex, exception

I am working on window form which is already created and i have to use that code and process further now the think is that that code work on one place but it wont work on other it will given me an error message length cannot be less than zero

This is my code:

aspx.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;

namespace AQCConsolidator1
{ 
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> list = new List<String>();
        List<String> list1 = new List<String>();

        string request = @"RP/DCA1S219C/DCA1S219C            SL/SU   9APR13/2223Z   4YYTR7                 
 45 FA PAX 257-7242858184/ETOS/USD736.23/08APR13/DCA1S211E/49881                
   134/S3-6/P1                                                              
 46 FA PAX 257-7242858185/ETOS/USD736.23/08APR13/DCA1S211E/49881                
   134/S3-6/P2                                                              
 030 AF/FA 257-7242215364/ETOS/USD778.23/07APR13/DCA1S219C/                  
    49881134/OS 850 K 31MAY TIAVIE/OS 087 K 31MAY VIEJFK/OS                 
    088 L 09JUN JFKVIE/OS 847 L 10JUN VIETIA/MBYETI/PETRAQ(                 
    ADT)                                                                    
030 AF/FA 257-7242215365/ETOS/USD778.23/07APR13/DCA1S219C/                  
    49881134/OS 850 K 31MAY TIAVIE/OS 087 K 31MAY VIEJFK/OS                 
    088 L 09JUN JFKVIE/OS 847 L 10JUN VIETIA/MBYETI/JORGJIE(                
    ADT)                                                                    
030 RF-WS-NMC-US/WSTMTFTP CR-DCA1S219C 49881134 SU 9999WS/RO                
    -9CCF46CE TNGW33TMT 00000000 07APR1829Z                                 
030/035 CF/FA 257-7242215364/ETOS/USD778.23/07APR13/DCA1S219C/                  
    49881134/OS 850 K 31MAY TIAVIE/OS 088 L 09JUN JFKVIE/OS                 
    087 K 31MAY VIEJFK/OS 847 L 10JUN VIETIA/MBYETI/PETRAQ(                 
    ADT)                                                                    
030/035 AF/FA 257-7242215364/ETOS/USD778.23/07APR13/DCA1S219C/                  
    49881134/OS 850 K 31MAY TIAVIE/OS 087 K 31MAY VIEJFK/                   
    MBYETI/PETRAQ(ADT)

string request1 = @"RP/DCA1S219C/DCA1S219C            SL/SU   7FEB13/2215Z   8TXSAK                 
36 FA PAX 125-7239038457/ETBA/07FEB13/DCA1S211E/49881134                       
   /S4-5/P3                                                                 
37 FA PAX 125-7239038458/ETBA/07FEB13/DCA1S211E/49881134                       
   /S4-5/P1                                                                 
38 FA PAX 125-7239038459/ETBA/07FEB13/DCA1S211E/49881134                @       
   /S4-5/P2                                                                 
39 FB PAX 0700449140 TTP/ET/RT/INVJ OK ETICKET/S4-5/P1-3                       
40 FE PAX BA ONLY/NONREF/NONEND SEE GGAIRBAGUSA -BG:BA/S4-5/P3                 
41 FE PAX BA ONLY/NONREF/NONEND SEE GGAIRBAGUSA -BG:BA                         
   /S4-5/P1-2                                                               
42 FI PAX 0700449140 INV 0011436178/S4-5/P1-3                                  
43 FI PAX 0700449140 INV 0011436178/S6/P1-3                                    
44 FI PAX 0700449140 INV 0011436178/S7/P1-3                                    
45 FM *M*0.00A                                                                 
46 FP CHECK                                                                    
47 FT *BT1195364                                                               
48 FV PAX BA/S4-5/P3                                                           
49 FV PAX BA/S4-5/P1-2                                                         
50 FY BULK/TBULK";
string request2 = @"RP/DCA1S219C/DCA1S219C            SL/SU   9APR13/2223Z   4YYTR7                 
 45 FA PAX 257-7242858184/ETOS/USD736.23/08APR13/DCA1S211E/49881                
   134/S3-6/P1                                                              
 46 FA PAX 257-7242858185/ETOS/USD736.23/08APR13/DCA1S211E/49881                
   134/S3-6/P2                                                              
 47 FB PAX 0800499541 TTP/ET/INVJ/RT OK ETICKET/S3-6/P1-2                       
 48 FE *M*//REFTHRUAGT/NONEND                                                   
 49 FI PAX 0800499541 INV 0011466820/S3-6/P1-2                                  
 50 FI PAX 0800499541 INV 0011466820/S7/P1-2                                    
 51 FI PAX 0800499541 INV 0011466820/S8/P1-2                                    
 52 FM *M*8                                                                     
 53 FP CHECK                                                                    
 54 FT *815ZU                                                                   
 55 FV PAX OS/S3-6/P1-2";

list.Add(request);
list.Add(request1);
list.Add(request2);

        MyClass1 obj1 = new MyClass1();
        DataTable datatable1 = obj1.GetNumber(list);
        }
    }
}
```

if i remove request from my aspx.cs file then this code work but if i include it it give this error still waiting for reply i add check condition but still it give me error

this is my class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace AQCConsolidator1
{
class MyClass1
{
    string output;
    string subs;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;

    public DataTable GetNumber(List<string> request)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("TickitNumber", typeof(string));

        foreach (string data in request)
        {
            string item = data;
            while (item.Trim() != "")
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                int r1 = item.IndexOf("\r",3);
                subs = item.Substring(0, r1); ///Got error in this line
                if (subs.Contains("ET"))
                {
                    Regex regexs = new Regex(@"[0-9||-]{14}");
                    foreach (Match m in regexs.Matches(subs))
                    {
                        output = m.ToString();
                        dr["TickitNumber"] = output;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                item = item.Substring(subs.Length);
                r1 = item.IndexOf("\r\n", 0);
                item = item.Substring(r1);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: *Where* is the error? You've presented a lot of code, and only a vague description of what's happening.

Comment: Have you stepped through it with the debugger to be sure you have more than an empty string?

Comment: `item.IndexOf("\r",3)` probably there is no `"\r"` in `item` so this will return `-1` and then you'll be trying to `item.Substring(0, -1)` which won't work.

Comment: It can't find an `\r` in the `item` string, so it returns -1, which gets passed to the substring and there's your error.

Comment: Ah, I see where the error is now - but it's buried in a lot of code, and should be called out more clearly.

Comment: This `int r1 = item.IndexOf("\r",3);` will be -1, if \r is not in the input

Comment: @Nolonar - Woops, misread the message. Thanks.

Comment: yes i use debug my value

Comment: @corak you are rite but how to solve this problem

Comment: i got why i got this error but i dont know how to solve this i guess this is stupid but can you guys help this is the whole code you can try it on your machine if you want

Comment: int r1=item.IndexOf("\r",3) in used to break line though loop

Answer (score 8):

```
int r1 = item.IndexOf("\r",3);
subs = item.Substring(0, r1); ///Got error in this line
```

[IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx) will return -1 as the index if the string is not found. Thus, you are attempting to call [SubString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) from index 0 to index -1 on the next line. You should add a check to ensure "\r" is found before continuing.

Comment: how to add check @Esoteric

Comment: @amitesh - Surely you know how to use an if statement!  You would use something like `if (r1 >= 0) { //code here }`  Only execute the rest of the code if r1 >= 0

Comment: error on item = item.Substring(subs.Length); this line that startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.

Comment: The think is that if i run request1 and another request say request 2 with different ticket the same code work but it won't work for the request